# Passing value of one component to another Angular

Tags: javascript, css, angular, html, typescript

i have an input element in a component like so :

```
   <input #inputDate
          (blur)="realDate(inputDate.value); inputDate.value='' ">
```

and then i want to use (show) the value of the inputDate on another component, how can i do it?
im new to angular, any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send it to a parent component, bind it to a ngModel and use event emitter to send this value.

If you want to send it to child component, use @Input decorator. ([parent-to-child](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#pass-data-from-parent-to-child-with-input-binding))

However, as you want to send the value from html, you can use jquery or document.querySelector to get the value

[This](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction) might help you

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send your component to a parent component, you can use the `@Output()` decorator and an Event Emitter together to send the value to a parent component by doing something like:

```
@Output()
public input: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();

<my-input (input)="onInputChange()"></my-input>

// Method to detect for changes on #myInput
public onMyInputChanges(): void {
    // ...
    input.emit(<#myInputValue>);
}
```

I'll leave it as an exercise for you to figure out how to detect changes to your input element above.

If you want to send your value to a child component, you can use the `@Input()` decorator and pass it along as such:

```
<input #myInput [(ngModel)]="inputValue">

public inputValue: string = '';

<child-component [value]="inputValue"></child-component>
```

Because you want to use the value directly from the HTML, consider using the `@ViewChild` decorator which would allow you to use your local reference `#inputDate` to get the value, like so:

```
@ViewChild('inputDate')
public myInput: HTMLInputElement;
```

And then you can access your value through `myInput.value` and either use it on your component or pass it around with the above methods.

You can also look into using `Services` which might help you reuse some of this logic across several components if that's your use case (e.g. emitting the value from a `Subject` and having multiple components listen to changes on your input).

Comment: okay, i finally able to configure how to use the ngModel directive, now the question is how to pass the value of "inputValue" to another component, let say i just want to show it through <label> or <h1> or  <p> tag.

Comment: Use any of the above methods. Is this other component a child or parent component? Else, you can use a Service.

Comment: so the situation is now, the two components are not related, i just route them through button and a link to go back, so i want the user to input a date, bind them with ngModel directive, and change the format using datePipe, and when the user click the button, the app route them to another component, that show the new formatted date from the component before, but i don't know how to do it.